# Docker difference docker run[...] docker container run [...]

Tags: linux, docker

Is it difference between this commands?

```
docker container run -d --name moby-counter --network moby-counter -p 8080:80 russmckendrick/moby-counter
docker run -itd --name moby-counter --network moby-counter -p 9090:80 russmckendrick/moby-counter
```

In addition then why in second command uses -i(Interactive) and -t(TTY)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker container run` is equivalent to `docker run`, as well as nearly all `docker container` commands can be found without `container` subset.

About `-it`. `t` creates console (`tty`), and `i` forwards your input to docker. That means you can use `-t` when you just need to observe the output, but you need both when container expects some input from you.